# ASP.NET CORE localization outputs quote in Razor view

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, localization, quote

I have the following code in a Razor view:

```
<abbr title='@Localizer["AnswerTip"]'>
    <label asp-for="MyModelField" class="control-label"></label>
</abbr>
```

The translation works fine, except that the localized value in French has a single quote in it.  Because of this, the HTML `title` attribute value in French is truncated after the single quote.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

**Here is an example of what it does:**

- Value in English = Can you help?
- Translated value in French = Pouvez-vous m'aider?
- Value that displays in French (truncated) = Pouver-vous m

Comment: please try 
 Replace("'", @"\'") Function

Comment: @Hardik - Thanks but I am looking for a generic way to do this, that would work for any languages.  There has to be a better way...